# Filter rows of one column which is alphabet, numbers or hyphen in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows, I need to check `room` column:

```
   id    room
0   1   A-102
1   2     201
2   3    B309
3   4   C·102
4   5  E_1089
```

The correct format of this column should be `numbers`, `alphabet` or `hyphen`, otherwise, fill `check` column with `incorrect`

The expected result is like this:

```
   id    room      check
0   1   A-102        NaN
1   2     201        NaN
2   3    B309        NaN
3   4   C·102  incorrect
4   5  E_1089  incorrect
```

Here informal syntax can be:

```
df.loc[<filter1> | (<filter2>) | (<filter3>), 'check'] = 'incorrect'
```

Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.match` to force all characters:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df.room.str.match('^[a-zA-Z\d\-]*$'), np.NaN, 'incorrect')
```

Or `str.contains` with negation pattern:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])'), 'incorrect', np.NaN)
```

Output:

```
   id    room      check
0   1   A-102        nan
1   2     201        nan
2   3    B309        nan
3   4   C·102  incorrect
4   5  E_1089  incorrect
```

If you want to *update* the existing `check` column, use `loc` access. For example:

```
df.loc[df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])'), 'check'] = 'incorrect'
# or safer when `NaN` presents
# df.loc[df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])') == True, 'check'] = 'incorrect'
```

Comment: Thanks, if `check` column already existed, could I use your code?

Comment: Sorry, it raises an error `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`, with `df.loc[df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])'), 'check'] = 'incorrect'`

Comment: Your `room` column has `NaN` values, just compare the series: `df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])') == True` then.

Comment: if it’s NaN, return incorrect also, how could I modify your code?

Comment: `df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])', na=True)` should do the trick

Comment: It's weird `df.loc[df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])', na=True), 'check'] = 'incorrect'` works well with test data, but for the my real data, it returns `incorrect` for numbers rows.