# Check whether one column's data type is number or NaN in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
   id    room   area                    check
0   1   A-102  world                      NaN
1   2     NaN     24   room name is not valid
2   3    B309    NaN                      NaN
3   4   C·102     25   room name is not valid
4   5  E_1089  hello   room name is not valid
5   6      27    NaN                      NaN
6   7      27    NaN                      NaN
```

I want to check whether `area` columns is valid data format, if it's either `numbers` or `NaN`s, then consider it's as valid data, eitherwise, update `check` column with `area is not a number`.

I tried with `df.loc[df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True), 'check'] = 'area is not a number'`, but not get what I needed.

How could I get an expected result like this:

```
   id    room   area                                          check
0   1   A-102  world                           area is not a number
1   2     NaN     24                         room name is not valid
2   3    B309    NaN                                            NaN
3   4   C·102     25                         room name is not valid
4   5  E_1089  hello   room name is not valid; area is not a number
5   6      27    NaN                                            NaN
6   7      27    NaN                                            NaN
```

Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, only invert mask by `~`:

```
df.loc[~df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True), 'check'] = 'area is not a number' 

print(df)
   id    room   area                 check
0   1   A-102  world  area is not a number
1   2     NaN     24                   NaN
2   3    B309    NaN                   NaN
3   4   C·102     25                   NaN
4   5  E_1089  hello  area is not a number
5   6      27    NaN                   NaN
6   7      27    NaN                   NaN
```

Or use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['check'] = df['check'].where(df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True),
                                'area is not a number')
```

EDIT:

```
m1 = df.room.str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])', na = True)
m2 = df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True)
v1 = 'room name is not valid'
v2 = 'area is not a number'


df['check'] = np.where(m1 & ~m2, v1 + ', ' + v2, 
              np.where(m1, v1,
              np.where(~m2, v2, None)))

print(df)
   id    room   area                                         check
0   1   A-102  world                          area is not a number
1   2     NaN     24                        room name is not valid
2   3    B309    NaN                                          None
3   4   C 102     25                        room name is not valid
4   5  E_1089  hello  room name is not valid, area is not a number
5   6      27    NaN                                          None
6   7      27    NaN                                          None
```

Comment: If `check` column already have content, for example for row 5, if `check` content is `room name is not valid`, now I need to apped `area is not a number`, then it becomes `room name is not valid; area is not a number`. How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon - So is necessary test same way column `room` ? If change `A-102` to `102` then for first row is `room name is valid; area is not a number`  and for row 5 `room name is not valid; area is not a number` ?

Comment: Please check my updated question, also the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64674083/filter-rows-of-one-column-which-is-alphabet-numbers-or-hyphen-in-pandas

Comment: @ahbon - answer was edited, added `None`, because `np.select` convert `np.nan` to string `'nan'`

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me solved the first question also.

Comment: Sorry, there are errors for the real data with first mask `m1` (room is `27`, but it returns `room name is not valid`), however `df.loc[df['room'].str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])') == True, 'check'] = 'room name is not valid'` is OK, I dont know why this happens, but I'm going to test again.

Comment: Is `27` string? Can you test by `m1 = df.room.astype(str).str.contains('([^a-zA-Z\d\-])', na=True)
m2 = df.area.astype(str).str.contains('^\d+$', na = True)` ?

Comment: It's Ok right now for `m1`, but for `m2`, when `area` is `NaN`s, it returns also `area is not a number`, in fact, I hope it returns `NaN`s or `None`s for `check` column.

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible change data sample?

Comment: Sure, but it's not English, I'm afraid it's not easy to understand. Tried again after removed `astype(str)` for `m2`, it's ok right now. Many thanks. One more question, if I have many columns to check, so there will be many `m`s and `v`s, is there a easy way append check results?

Comment: @ahbon - Hard question, maybe the best some custom function